# How to create scheduled job that runs every minute in apex salesforce

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

I am planning to create a scheduled job using scheduled apex in salesforce. I know that we can write and run the job for every one hour. I would like to know if there is a way we can run the code for every minute instead of every one hour.
I know the following code will work fine for every one hour.

```
System.schedule('Scheduled Job', '0 15 * * * ?', new scheduledJob());
```

Answer (score 2):

You **can't** schedule by the second. The smallest hypothetical schedule you can perform with a single `Scheduleable` interface is **once an hour**. if you need a smaller time frame than this, use an external integration, a trigger, or an outbound message (using Workflow Rules)